# Allow some illegal gathering without knowing it

Tags: administration

First, I don't know if it's the right site to post this so sorry if not.

I want to create a website which permits users to create events.

In a legal and webmaster way, am I responsible if users create illegal events (like racist gathering)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To some extend, yes. Your site, your domain, your responsibility.

**But**; I assume you have ToS which tells people not to do hatefull/offensive on your site, with some kind of penalty ((temp)ban, removal, ...). If you check events which are flagged as bad, and delete/cancel those when encounter you shouldn't get in much trouble. I find that "You will be held responsible for your own content" works well too.

If someone reports something bad, and you decide they're correct and delete it, you should be safe.

*I'm no legal expert, but this has worked for me so far. When someone complains, I review it and send a polite message (whatever their tone might've been!) regarding my actions.*